# How do you use your classes in HTML to call in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues with my process, since I'm a newbie in HTML-CSS.

The thing is...Whenever I begin my CSS codes I'm having some issues with the

`text-align:`

`font-family`

`font-size`

`font-weight`

they all seem too similar to me, sometimes I end up doing something that I didn't wanted to.

As an example, in this print
[image: i wanted to put these 2 images side by side]

Anyway, I'm taking back all the study I had with CSS so that I can strengthen my knowledge.

I just wanted to share what I'm going through. A lot of things in the CSS seems the same to me and it's confusing!

Comment: have you tried googling about this stuff, for example my google search of "multiple class css" returns one of this site https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/ , it explains some stuff like using multiple class name to determine what style will be picked, and probably some other stuff if you explore the site. 
for your base issue, a simple base class should be enough, so you can attribute that base class to basically all element of html that need that particular style

Comment: @encryptoferia Yes! I always do a good google search about the issue I'm having. But, as I told...I'm a beginner, I have something around 40 days studying CSS/HTML and later on JS every single day for 3 to 5 hours. So, I do think that these "confusions" can arise...Anyway, thank you for your link to css-tricks. Whenever I can, I use the w3 school links aswell.

Comment: _have something around 40 days studying CSS/HTML_ - Keep working at it, that's how you get better. I've been doing HTML/CSS/JS for 24 years. It changes and evolves over time. Try to avoid the w3 schools links and use the [MDN instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS). Also, unfortunately, this is question is off-topic for Stack Overflow since you are not asking a specific coding question.

Comment: @disinfor I'm sorry, since I'm a begginer I'm still learning about StackOverflow. Just wanted to share something and receive a feedback. Sorry about not being specific. Thank you for your advice, I'm not giving up. Studying every single day.

Answer (score 1):

So text-align determines whether your text is oriented at the left, right, or center of its container, much like the alignment feature on Microsoft Word. Font-family is what kind of font you're using (Arial, Times New Roman, etc.). Font-size is just that, how large your font is, while font-weight determines whether your font is bold or not.

If you want the 2 images to be side by side, rather than one on top of the other, I recommend setting the parent container's display property to flex and its flex-direction to row like this:

```
.parent-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

You can learn more about Flexbox at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/   I found this website invaluable when I was a CSS beginner.

Comment: Great! 

Thank you so much for answering me! 
I'll try what you just did and definitely will check the link!